# Allow selecting of row once for each datatable shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using `datatables.js` https://www.datatables.net/ and am running in to a problem where I want the user to select one row for reach table shown.

I've tried several things but can't get it to work, my script checks all the datatables instead of the one you are selecting in. Which I understand because in my code I am fetching all the tables by using `var table = $('table').DataTable();`

But I have no idea how I could specify it so it checks if a `selected` class is set on one of the rows in the datatables.

```
var table = $('table').DataTable();

$('table tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    }
    else {
        table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
} );
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the selection to work on multiple tables? Eg. You have 3 tables and you want each table to have it's own selection handling. If that's the case I see two options, either setup each table separately with IDs or in the `on()` event get the parent table **inside** the function, something like `var table = $(this).closest("table")`

Comment: Yes exactly so I got 5 tables, all 5 the tables have data inside them. And I wanna make it so when someone clicks a row it gets highlighted (by adding a class), and allowing it to only highlight one row for each table. I will check out your suggestions @amura.cxg

Comment: I tried your second guess and it worked @amura.cxg Thanks alot!

Comment: Awesome! I'll post it in an answer so you can mark this as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `on()` event get the row's table instead of using the table defined outside of the function.

**Code**

```
$('table tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    var table = $(this).closest("table");
    if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    }
    else {
        table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
} );
```

Comment: Thank god that jQuery has functions like these, makes life easier. Thanks alot for sorting this out for me!

Comment: what is `table.$('tr.selected')`?

Comment: inside the table search for a `tr` with the class `selected` @charlietfl

Comment: @Jordy is correct, see [this](http://datatables.net/reference/api/%24()) for an explanation